# The inverse of disformal metric?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, metric-tensor, modified-gravity

From [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01849) paper on equation (62), they show the disformal transformation of metric
$$
\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}=A(\phi,X)g_{\mu\nu}+B(\phi,X)\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla_\nu\phi,~~~\tilde{\phi}=\phi.
$$
Then the equation (63) they define the inverse of this metric
$$
\tilde{g}^{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{A}\left({g^{\mu\nu}-\frac{B}{A-2XB}\nabla^\mu\phi\nabla^\nu\phi}\right).$$
I cannot find any clean method to derive the second equation from the first and cannot find any source show such derivation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the only things in town, ie, $g_{\mu\nu}$ and $\partial_\mu\phi$. Therefore, for the consideration of symmetry of $g^{\mu\nu}$, all you can construct is

$$\tilde{g}^{\mu\nu}=C g^{\mu\nu} + D \partial^\mu\phi\partial^\nu\phi,$$

To find C & D use the following relation,

$$\tilde{g}_{\mu\sigma}\tilde{g}^{\sigma\nu}=g_{\mu\sigma}g^{\sigma\nu}=\delta_\mu^\nu
$$